# Find all the numbers in one file that are not in another file in python

Tags: python, arrays, file, out-of-memory

There are two files, say FileA and FileB and we need to find all the numbers that are in FileA which is not there in FileB. All the numbers in the FileA are sorted and all the numbers in FileB are sorted. For example,

Input:

```
FileA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]
FileB = [1, 3, 4, 6, ...]
```

Output:

```
[2, 5, ...]
```

The memory is very limited and even one entire file cannot be loaded into memory at a time. Also linear or lesser time complexity is needed.

So if the files are small enough to fit in the memory, we could load them and initialize its contents as two sets and then take a set difference so that the problem is solved in O(1) or constant time complexity.

```
set(contentsofFileA)-set(contentsofFileB)
```

But since the files are so big, they won't be able to load entirely into the memory and so this is not possible.

Also, another approach would be to use a brute force method with batch processing. So, we load a chunk or batch of data from FileA and then a batch from FileB and then compare it and then the next chunk from FileB and so on. Then after the FileA chunk is checked over all the elements in FileB then load the next batch from FileA and this continues. But this would create an O(n^2) or quadratic time complexity and not efficient for a very large file with large entries.

The problem is required to be solved in linear or lesser time complexity and without loading the entire files into memory. Any help?

Comment: Are the files already in sorted ordered?

Comment: Is there a possibility to load at least one file fully in the memory and the other file via batch process ?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle The files are sorted seperatley

Comment: @venkatakrishnan not even one file can be loaded entirely in memory

Comment: Are all numbers in file b guarranteed to be in file a? If they are then you can just read them in parallel and continue the read on file b until you get to the next number thats in file a

Comment: Excellent so they are in sorted order when you come to process them?  do you need to list numbers that are missing in file A from file B and numbers missing from File B in file A

Comment: https://fnc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#list and https://fnc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fnc.sequences.difference this may help

Comment: @Sayse all the numbers in FileB not necessarily need to be in FileA

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Missing numbers in FileB from FileA

Comment: @GeekSambhu I'm sorry I don't understand completely. But if you are suggesting to load them into an array, that is not possible in this situation as the memory will overload and memory error would occur.

Comment: Are all the numbers in the file on the same line? Can you provide a bit more information/context?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to read the files line by line since you don't have so much memory and you need a linear solution you can do this with iter if your files are line based, otherwise see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/519653/5120089):

First in your terminal you can do this to generate some test files:

```
seq 0 3 100 > 3k.txt
seq 0 2 100 > 2k.txt
```

Then you run this code:

```
i1 = iter(open("3k.txt"))
i2 = iter(open("2k.txt"))
a = int(next(i1))
b = int(next(i2))
aNotB = []
# bNotA = []
while True:
    try:
        if a < b:
            aNotB += [a]
            a = int(next(i1, None))
        elif a > b:
            # bNotA += [a]
            b = int(next(i2, None))
        elif a == b:
            a = int(next(i1, None))
            b = int(next(i2, None))
    except TypeError:
        if not b:
            aNotB += list(i1)
            break
        else:
            # bNotA += list(i1)
            break
print(aNotB)
```

Output:

> [3, 9, 15, 21, 27, 33, 39, 45, 51, 57, 63, 69, 75, 81, 87, 93, 99]
>   If you want both the result for aNotB and bNotA you can uncomment those two lines.

Timing comparison with Andrej Kesely's answer:

```
$ seq 0 3 1000000 > 3k.txt
$ seq 0 2 1000000 > 2k.txt
$ time python manual_iter.py        
python manual_iter.py  0.38s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.387 total
$ time python heapq_groupby.py        
python heapq_groupby.py  1.11s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 1.116 total
```

Comment: I guess this is one way to do it. Basically, you are using two-pointers and iterating over the arrays once so it is in O(n) and since it is sorted I guess this will work. 
But we are still loading the whole file, isn't it?

Comment: @ArjunMuraleedharan no we are loading the files line by line. Iter lazy loads the file.

Comment: @ArjunMuraleedharan No, we aren't loading the whole file, that's the point of this algorithm

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - it's fastest :)

Comment: @yukashimahuksay Thank you so much for your answer.

If the arrays were not sorted what would you suggest??

Comment: @ArjunMuraleedharan I think you should post a whole new question because that's really a whole different issue which I believe is impossible to solve in O(n) with your memory limits.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay that cannot be done in O(n), but other than sorting you have any ideas on how to approach that problem?

Comment: @ArjunMuraleedharan You can use heuristic methods with hashing, you can also split B to k chunks, add each chunk to a set, then remove all the elements of each set from A in k iterations over A.

Answer (score 7):

As files are sorted you can just iterate through each line at a time, if the line of file A is less than the line of file B then you know that A is not in B so you then increment file A only and then check again. If the line in A is greater than the line in B then you know that B is not in A so you increment file B only. If A and B are equal then you know line is in both so increment both files. while in your original question you stated you were interested in entries which are in A but not B, this answer will extend that and also give entries in B not A. This extends the flexability but still allows you so print just those in A not B.

```
def strip_read(file):
    return file.readline().rstrip()

in_a_not_b = []
in_b_not_a = []
with open("fileA") as A:
    with open("fileB") as B:
        Aline = strip_read(A)
        Bline = strip_read(B)
        while Aline or Bline:
            if Aline < Bline and Aline:
                in_a_not_b.append(Aline)
                Aline = strip_read(A)
            elif Aline > Bline and Bline:
                in_b_not_a.append(Bline)
                Bline = strip_read(B)
            else:
                Aline = strip_read(A)
                Bline = strip_read(B)

print("in A not in B", in_a_not_b, "\nin B not in A", in_b_not_a)
```

OUTPUT for my sample Files

```
in A not in B ['2', '5', '7'] 
in B not in A ['6']
```

Comment: How is this in any way a new answer? there are already two answers exactly doing this.

Comment: I only see one answer doing this by reading the files line by line. and it makes the assumption that its only interested in the files which are in A but not in B. This code will loop through files of varying length and actually list items which are in A and not in B and also list items which are in B but not in A

Comment: For eacmple in mattias case it will stop comparing when it reaches the end of either file. even if the other file still had entries in it which means those entires which have not been read yet wont be listed as not being in the other file

Comment: But that is not what the OP was asking. iter also reads files line by line.

Comment: I accept the issue with mattias answer. that answer is wrong for files of varying length.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay yes sorry you iter answer will also iterate over the files. but am not sure the point of your argument. my code indeed provides a different answer from any other. It offers an extention and flexability to the OP question but also solves it as it includes answer to either file missing entries.

Comment: I accept that it adds an unwanted extension, you need to edit your answer so I can remove my vote.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I have now corrected my answer.

Comment: It was certainly a nice question and its good to see it inspiring minds

Comment: You are missing the call to `int`. Otherwise you get problems like `"9" > "10"`. Also, you can open multiple files in one `with` statement.

Answer (score 5):

You can combine `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)) and `heapq.merge` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge)) to iterate through `FileA` and `FileB` lazily (it works as long the files are sorted!)

```
FileA = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
FileB = [1, 3, 4, 6]

from itertools import groupby
from heapq import merge

gen_a = ((v, 'FileA') for v in FileA)
gen_b = ((v, 'FileB') for v in FileB)

for v, g in groupby(merge(gen_a, gen_b, key=lambda k: int(k[0])), lambda k: int(k[0])):
    if any(v[1] == 'FileB' for v in g):
        continue
    print(v)
```

Prints:

```
2
5
```

---

EDIT (Reading from files):

```
from itertools import groupby
from heapq import merge

gen_a = ((int(v.strip()), 1) for v in open('3k.txt'))
gen_b = ((int(v.strip()), 2) for v in open('2k.txt'))

for v, g in groupby(merge(gen_a, gen_b, key=lambda k: k[0]), lambda k: k[0]):
    if any(v[1] == 2 for v in g):
        continue
    print(v)
```

Benchmark:

Generating files with 10_000_000 items:

```
seq 0 3 10000000 > 3k.txt
seq 0 2 10000000 > 2k.txt
```

The script takes ~10sec to complete:

```
real    0m10,656s
user    0m10,557s
sys 0m0,076s
```

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thank you so much, man. But one thing I don't understand is why is it taking too much time for very very big numbers if this is also linear time complexity?

Comment: @ArjunMuraleedharan Yes, the complexity is O(n). But in my answer I create lots of tuples for each element, for example `(int(v.strip()), 1)` Each tuple is object and creation of this object takes some "little" time. For long files, this time adds up.

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes that makes sense. But even when I try it with some sample array, it is taking more time than the other answer. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution based on file reading (asuming that each line hold a number):

```
results = []
with open('file1.csv') as file1, open('file2.csv') as file2:
        var1 = file1.readline()
        var2 = file2.readline()
        while var1:
            while var1 and var2:
                if int(var1) < int(var2):
                    results.append(int(var1))
                    var1 = file1.readline()
                elif int(var1) > int(var2):
                    var2 = file2.readline()
                elif int(var1) == int(var2):
                    var1 = file1.readline()
                    var2 = file2.readline()
            if var1:
                results.append(int(var1))
                var1 = file1.readline()
print(results)
output = [2, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: You are missing the calls to `int` before the comparisons. Otherwise you get problems like `"9" > "10"`. Also, you can open multiple files in one `with` statement.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed my code to handle that case as well. Thanks for the input! @Graipher

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the classic Knuth Sorting and Searching.
You may wish to consider reading [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645566/efficient-out-of-core-sorting),
[on-line lecture notes](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9d8d/14d9e7cc3f05e943934e8e473461e4b89477.pdf) pdf, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).
The stack question mentions something that I agree with, which is using unix sort command. Always, always test with your own data to ensure the method chosen is the most efficient for your data because some of these algorithms are data dependant.