# Python text help large files

Tags: python, python-3.x

this code works perfectly the only problem it doesnt work with Large txt files . 1GB text file . What can I do to fix?

```
import os

file_1 = open('file1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8').read().splitlines()
file_2 = open('file2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8').read().splitlines()
[file_2.remove(l) for l in file_1 if l in file_2]
with open('file2.txt', 'w') as new_file:
    [new_file.write(l + '\n') for l in file_2]
```

Comment: Can you define "doesnt work with large files"? do you mean you get a memory error (since you read both files into memory)? or do you mean its just really slow (since your calling `remove()` method of list. Are these files already sorted in order before you porcess them in this script?

Comment: That just takes some time in computing, it is natural, but there are ways computing time can be reduced.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
MemoryError

Comment: yeah so this happens because you try to read the entire file into memory. So for large files which are bigger than your memory this is impossible. as you wont have enough memory to hold the entire file contents. Instead you need to rethink how to appraoch this problem  in a way that allows you to read the file either line by line or in chunks

Comment: @ChrisDoyle  so whats the solution

Comment: well as we dont know your aim / objective its hard to say. As i already asked are both these files sorted. It seems you aim is to remove lines from file2 which exist in file 1 such that file 2 continas only lines that dont exist in file1. you dont mention if these files are sorted / ordered as that changes the complexity and runtime of such a problem

Comment: you could have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57287702/1212401 as its a similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the files without saving the content in memory. You can do it by using `with` on the input files

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Guy.SA\Desktop\fileB.txt', 'r') as file_2, open(r'C:\Users\Guy.SA\Desktop\fileC.txt', 'w') as new_file:
    for line_2 in file_2:
        with open(r'C:\Users\Guy.SA\Desktop\fileA.txt', 'r') as file_1:
            for line_1 in file_1:
                if line_1 == line_2:
                    break
            else:
                new_file.write(line_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use file object for this:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file_1,
     open('file2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file_2:

    for line in file1: # or file 2
        # Do what you need to do with reading it line by line
```

Also note that:

> `with` will close file automatically after.

Comment: What if he wants to only write lines from file1 which dont exist in file 2?

Comment: Then he can fill a list or dict for filling it with lines, which will not need to load a file in memory at once, or he can open them one by one.